# How much slower is it really to run Babel standalone in browser compared to precompile?

Tags: babeljs

I don't know if anyone did a benchmark, but it would be interesting to see if Babel standalone is 2x slower, 10x or 100x slower to run in the browser compared to precompile the code. I know it's not recommended, that's not what this question is about.

Say using a React component with JSX works as a benchmark?

Comment: If you treat the time to load the page without Babel as "1", then the time it takes with Babel loaded is N for the amount of code it needs to build every pageload, so the only way to answer this question is to measure the page given your specific scripts.

Comment: @loganfsmyth Sure, but it would be nice to know if this N is trivial compared to, say, loading a picture or doing an Ajax call. Now, if only it was possible to cache the compiled code in the browser. :)

Comment: Unless you're talking a pretty small JS file, I'd consider it to always be a non-trivial amount of time. Even ignoring that though, N is dependent on your code size, and then there will be a constant multiple based on the processor speed of the device running Babel. If a user is viewing your site on a phone for instance, then what was trivial on your computer may be absolutely terrible. "10x or 100x slower" is meaningless when you don't control the device running Babel.

Comment: @loganfsmyth "Guessing is not engineering." ;)